# Is "Abbau" a correct term when reffering to oil

Tags: word-usage, technical-terminology

When referring to Oil "Erdöl", is the term "Abbau" correct, or is it just for coal and other minerals?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's "Förderung" or "Gewinnung".
"Abbau" doesn't fit, because you just have channel the oil, or pump it out. There is no "hacking" involved. Also, "Abbau" in context of oil means to "degrade" it.

"Förderung" is also used for coal and other minerals like gold, by the way.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is that "Abbau" includes visible excavations on the surface (Brown coal mining), whereas "Förderung" is usually underground.

Comment: @Mark I think this would be a wrong rule of thumb. See 6a in http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abbau . There they mention both Tiefbau and Tagebau. And IMHO there is nothing unusual or wrong in "Im Ruhrgebiet wird die Steinkohle unter Tage abgebaut.", for example.

Answer (score 8):

There are already the correct answers about "Förderung" or "Gewinnung" for liquid oil.

But oil can also be find as [Ölschiefer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96lschiefer) ([Oil shale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_shale))
This [Ölschiefer is `abgebaut`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96lschiefer#Gewinnung.2C_Extraktion_und_Verwendung_von_.C3.96lschiefer), followed by the extraction of the oil.

Again, there is no `Abbau` of the oil itself, but for the pre-product `Ölschiefer`.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is only used for mining raw materials in solid state and wouldn't work for liquids or gases.

***Abbau*** literally translates to deconstruct, to take apart. It is the opposite of ***aufbauen***, even when used metaphorically (aufbauen: build up, improve; abbauen: reduce, degrade). Both meanings don't really fit in the context of extracting liquids from the ground.

As Emanuel already stated, the most common terms are ***Förderung*** and ***Gewinnung***.